# Android Bluetooth connection ProgressDialog implementation using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bluetooth

I'm trying to implement an Android app which must find bluetooth devices in its area(there is a condition for the bluetooth device name HXMXXXXXX, X - is a number). I've done this part and it is working fine, and now I'm trying to show a progress dialog while the operation of searching devices is performed. I tried to do this by using AsyncTask but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
package com.yast;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class ConnectionScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
    //Declaration of components
    private static final String TAG = "ConnectionScreen";
    public static final String BROADCAST = "PACKAGE_NAME.android.action.broadcast";
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private Button buttonSearch;
    private CheckBox checkBoxAutoConnect;
    private ListView listOfDevices;
    private TextView statusId;
    private TextView statusConnection;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothadapt;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> deviceAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection_screen);

    linkViewToResources();

    //ListView
    List<String> arrayListOfDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayListOfDevices.add("unu");
    arrayListOfDevices.add("doi");


    listOfDevices.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);



    bluetoothadapt=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(bluetoothadapt==null){
        statusConnection.setText("Not supported");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your device does not support Bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        buttonSearch.setEnabled(false);
    } else{
        buttonSearch.setEnabled(true);
    }




}



 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    }

    private void linkViewToResources(){
        buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                find(view);

            }
        });
        checkBoxAutoConnect = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxAutoconnect);
        listOfDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOfDevices);
        deviceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    }


  final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // add the name and the MAC address of the object to the arrayAdapter
                // get paired devices
                if (device.getName().startsWith("HXM") && device.getName().length() == 9) {
                    deviceAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    //deviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    };


  public void find(View view) {
        if (bluetoothadapt.isDiscovering()) {
            // the button is pressed when it discovers, so cancel the discovery
            bluetoothadapt.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        else {
            deviceAdapter.clear();
            bluetoothadapt.startDiscovery();
            new ProgressTask().execute(null, null, null);


        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            if (bReceiver != null) {
                unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.connection_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }


 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



 public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


        /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */
        private ProgressDialog dialog;


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
            this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
            this.dialog.show();
        }



 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    deviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}



    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
            try{
                Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST);
                sendBroadcast(intent);

               return true;
            } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:702)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
        at com.yast.ConnectionScreen$ProgressTask.onPreExecute(ConnectionScreen.java:171)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
        at com.yast.ConnectionScreen.find(ConnectionScreen.java:122)
        at com.yast.ConnectionScreen$1.onClick(ConnectionScreen.java:86)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 dialog = new ProgressDialog(ConnectionScreen.this);
```

instead of

```
 dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

You should pass `Activity` Context instead of `Application` Context.

Comment: Thankyou, it prints now the progress dialog, but it only appears for very short time. I want it to be there until the search is finished and the found devices are printed. Do you know why this isn't working?

Comment: @salam you need to implement all your logic in your `AsyncTask` `InBackground(.......)` method

Comment: @M D: but I think I have implemented the logic in the project. Do you mean to move it inside doInBackground() ?